# Define a directed-complete partial order of lists

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads

The List monad takes a set and produces the set of lists on that set.  The elements of the set become the symbols or objects of the list.  I would like to define a directed-complete partial order (dcpo) of lists.  A somewhat similar structure might be the interval domain which is a dcpo of real intervals.  I would also like to know if there are other domains that admit such structures.

One suggestion is that we define the dcpo by initial partial fragment.  So, for $l_1, l_2 \in List(X)$, $l_1 < l_2$ if  $l_2 = Concat(l_1,l_2')$.  Where the function $Concat$ is jus the concatenation function on lists.  We may also have to move to infinite lists, or streams.

Comment: Some questions:

1 - "The elements of the set become the symbols or objects of the list" - Is that your description of the unit $\eta_A: A\to \mathrm{List}(A)$ of the monad?

2 -  "I would like to define a directed-complete partial order (dcpo) of lists." - Is it that you want to define a dcpo on the set of all lists of a given type, i.e. on $\mathrm{List}(A)$?

Comment: @GerritBegher the eta function gives the single element lists with each element of the set as one of the lists.  I do think I want to define a dcpo on the set of all lists, ie on List(A).  The map of the monad would take all lists (ie List(A) and return the set of all domains of those lists.  So I am trying to make a concrete dcpo monad that applies specifically to the set of Lists.